# Can't Grant SLAVE MONITOR to user on MariaDB 10.6 Primary

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, mariadb-10.3, mariadb-10.6

We recently replaced an old MariaDB 10.3 primary with one of it's replicas which is running 10.6.x. Hoping that this would resolve a weird Primary/replica issue that we have had since creating the replicas.

The Struggle:
Per the MariaDB documentation in order for a user to have access to `SHOW REPLICA STATUS` (formerly `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`) in MariaDB 10.3 that user needed the `REPLICATION CLIENT` privilege. Furthermore `REPLICATION CLIENT` was renamed to `BINLOG MONITOR` in mariadb 10.5.2 and this Privilege does show up as `BINLOG MONITOR` when granting the `REPLICATION CLIENT` privilege on versions of 10.5.2 or newer. However, according to the [mariadb kb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#replication-client) (and confirmed by my experience) "Unlike `REPLICATION CLIENT` prior to MariaDB 10.5, `SHOW REPLICA STATUS` isn't included in this privilege, and `REPLICA MONITOR` is required". This has created a bit of a headache for me.

The old problem:
Due to the cups and ball trick MDB has decided to play with the `SHOW REPLICA STATUS` privilege I couldn't grant `REPLICA MONITOR` on the old primary without getting an error (because that privilege doesn't exist on 10.3) and `REPLICATION CLIENT` wasn't sufficient on the replicas (because `SHOW REPLICA STATUS` was moved to `REPLICA MONITOR`). This lead me to EOL the old primary and promote one of the 10.6 replicas to primary.

The new problem (or just the old problem persisting):
The problem however is the new primary which is running 10.6 is behaving almost exactly like the old primary (which, again was on 10.3). The only difference is when I grant `REPLICA MONITOR` now I don't get an error but the grant doesn't stick. I can `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and `SHOW GRANTS...` on the user but it isn't there.

So the question is what would cause a mariadb 10.6 Primary to behave like the former 10.3 primary in this scenario? is there some config or system variable I am unaware of?

FWIW the machine was rebooted a few times during the fail-over process but if that is the fix it can be done again. I have also tried granting `SLAVE MONITOR` which is the former version of `REPLICA MONITOR` but it doesn't stick either. I also tried granting BINLOG MONITOR which does stick but as I've already covered isn't sufficient on 10.6.

Comment: tl;dr: if granting REPLICA MONITOR silently fails, no error but nothing is granted -> run `mariadb-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading from 10.3, run [mariadb-upgrade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-upgrade). This will change the table structure of MariaDB to be able to handle the the privilege changes made in 10.5 The upgrade will also migrate to an equivalent grant.

Comment: thanks for the reply, once I've been able to try this out I'll update this with the results.

Comment: @DNate looking forward to that accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you ever went ahead and opened an issue for this with Mariadb. I ran into the same issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (and because of this from Mariadb 10.3 to 10.6). A database created with 10.3 cannot have users with the "slave monitor". But if I initialise a fresh database on 10.6 then the right can be granted.

I have created https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31426 for the issue

Comment: I did not, but it looks like you got an answer to yours which has lead to what is likely the answer for me (haven't tried it yet but I'm optimistic), so thanks for tagging this.

Comment: I did try running mariadb-upgrade and it solved the problem if you want to add it as an answer I'll accept that as the answer.